# Body missing sending array in a request for karate testing with Yaml

Tags: automation, request, yaml, karate

I have started working with karate and yml. I have been validating simple requests and responses. right now I'm trying to validate a response but I'm always receiving a 500 error due to "Required request body is missing".

I have been doing the same request with postman and it works correctly, it is also pointing at the correct URL so I think my problem lies in my yml formatting.

The Yml with the structure validation looks like this:

```
operationId: name
statusCode: 200
params: null
body:
  ids: [2, 4]
matchResponse: true
responseMatches: '##string'
responseMatchesEach: {}
```

I read my request using:

```
* def Request = read('path/whatever.yml')
```

My test fail in this line

```
* match responseStatus == 200
```

Because I get a 500 response. This 500 response happens when the body is not formatted correctly, and it is also telling me "Required request body is missing".

I tried to send the request with postman and it works perfectly (Selecting raw and JSON)

```
{
    "ids": [2,4]
}
```

So I'm pretty sure I'm not formatting the body correctly

Comment: sorry I can't help unless I get a way to replicate: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - my honest opinion is don't use YAML, it has too many edge cases for use in a test-automation tool

Answer (score 0):

The correct format ended up being this:

```
statusCode: 200
params: null
body:
  ids:
    - 2
    - 4
matchResponse: true
responseMatches: '##string'
responseMatchesEach: {}
```

Everywhere I looked I saw that the format used in the question was also valid, but it didn't work for some reason.